# Storing editText to variables

Tags: java, android, textview, android-edittext

Here is my current situation:

I have a regular xml page with a textView which when clicked opens a popup dialog.
This dialog contains 2 editText. Currently my code (OnClick – Done button) gets the value of both edit texts and puts them into the single  TextView. However when i open the pop-up again, instead of the two strings being listed in  its own editText (Where each string was originally inputted) the combined string which was stored in the text view appears in one edit text.
The issue is that although i’m getting the strings from 2 different editText’s and storing them into one textView. I cannot get each string back individually. 
I understand that i may have to store the string from each editText into variables and then i can use the variables to show the strings combined in the textView (and the editText – when i open the popup dialog again)
How would i go about this? 
Thank for your help

The code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
  /** Called when the activity is first created. */
  TextView showPopUpButton; //NEW
  EditText getInput; //NEW
  EditText getInput2; //NEW

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    showPopUpButton = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.buttonShowPopUp); //NEW
    showPopUpButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
        showPopUp3();           
      }
    });
  }

  private void showPopUp3() {
    AlertDialog.Builder helpBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    helpBuilder.setTitle("Enter PU Builder");
    LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
    View checkboxLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.popuplayout, null);

    getInput = (EditText)  checkboxLayout.findViewById(R.id.editText1); //MISTAKE
    getInput2 = (EditText)  checkboxLayout.findViewById(R.id.editText2); //MISTAKE
    getInput.setText(showPopUpButton.getText()); //New to keep the text in the editText when done is pressed
    getInput2.setText(getInput2.getText()); //New test

    helpBuilder.setView(checkboxLayout);
    helpBuilder.setPositiveButton("Done", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
      @Override  
      public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        showPopUpButton.setText(getInput.getText() + ", " + getInput2.getText()); //NEW
      }
    });

    AlertDialog helpDialog = helpBuilder.create();
    helpDialog.show();
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you be more clear?

Comment: Storing data to variables isn't the idea to go with since garbage collector can delete that data on the first occasion such as switching between applications, resuming your app after some time ect. Take a look on SharedPreferences. I think this is the best way of storing some data: 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html

Comment: my apologies, please see the revised question.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, yes, you need to store these EditText inputs separately. Keeping them in an array or List can make it more dynamic than naming each EditText input, but they would need to be kept separate.

Automating this using a [TestWatcher](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html) may make it less painfull.

Answer (score 0):

```
String variable_name = getInput2.getText().toString();
String variable_name2 = getInput.getText().toString();
String variable_name3 = variable_name + variable_name2;
```

From what I understand you should just get the Strings and store them, then concatenate them when you need to. I wish you would be more clear with your question.

Comment: my apologies, please see the revised question.